How to calculate Vout for this potential divider MOSFET circuit
I am currently working on a project, and for it I require a 875MHz square wave to run the clock of 4 9-bit shift registers. The problem is the only oscillator and shift register I could find and were compatible, were just not quite right for each other.
The output of the oscillator had it's low voltage at 3.04V min and 3.60V max and it's high voltage at 3.95V min and 4.650V max. However, the shift registers read a voltage of 3.005V to 3.375V as low and a voltage of 3.775V to 4.12V as high. The oscillator is a MC100EL1648 and the shift register is a MC100EP142.
So the problem is a large portion of the potential low output for the oscillator is above what the registers read as low meaning the output of the registers will be unpredictable.
I'm trying to use the MOSFET's (BLP9LA25SG) threshold voltage (2V and in the datasheet this is the same value for the quiescent voltage) and a small voltage supply (Vp) at the source to switch the MOSFET on and off at the low and high states of the oscillator. Then the resistors will determine what Vout will be when the MOSFET is on and off, creating my own voltage levels and allowing the registers to be run without error, but I'm struggling with the calculations.
I'm fine with the low state, that's just a potential divider (I think? Could absolutely be missing something) but the calculations for the on state are just beyond my scope of understanding currently
I am but a mere apprentice, and It's been a while since I've done a lot of this in school and my one disastrous year in uni so these MOSFET calculations are not really clear to me. In this question: How to calculate Vout from the MOSFET circuit I got sort of an idea but the circuit was a little different and the equations in the answers didn't include VDD and that's a pretty big part of what I'm doing here. I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something simple here and I'll kick myself when I find out but A little help would be greatly appreciated.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

These are in the same family for direct connection. Did you check the 50 Ohm voltage ?

maybe an attenuator will do scaling the signal down to ~70–90% of its original swing.

A common-source MOSFET solution is inappropriate at these frequencies, because of gate and miller capacitance, both of which will slow output slewing. Even if you did find the correct resistances for your design, bandwidth will be appallingly low.
The first page of MC100EL1648 datasheet mentions the use of EL16 or EL11 buffers, referring to the MC100EL16 and MC100EL11 devices, which have output potentials more closely matched to the inputs of the MC100EP142.
The MC100EL16 is particularly interesting, as it exposes an internal \$V_{BB}\$ reference representing the switching threshold. Your oscillator signal is single ended, for which this buffer can be used; the datasheet says "for single-ended input conditions, the unused differential input is connected to \$V_{BB}\$ as a switching reference voltage", implying that this threshold is somewhat flexible. You should explore the possibility of applying your own fixed and low impedance threshold potential to one of the buffer inputs.

I knew I'd kick myself, thanks a lot for this answer. I'd already looked at those parts because datasheet mentions you need them to drive multiple parts, but for some reason I didn't check the output voltages. Will try this out and let you know how it goes.

May be try this approach -

Choose where your voltages are referenced from - they must have a common frame of reference.
What is the assumed value of Rds under these condition? Is the MOSFET going to be operating in its ohmic or pinch-off region? Or are you going to express the divider in terms of Vds and the other resistors?
Remember Kirchoff's Voltage Law and apply.

Start with the above and go from there ...
